# Ant D pagination size position

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Is there a way to achieve this layout in ant d table pagination size

the default layout is only on the right or next on the pagination button.

This screen shot is the goal layout
[image]

I already make it. so far looks like on the layout.
[image]

my code

```
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}
    pagination={{
        // showSizeChanger: true,
        // showQuickJumper: true,
        defaultPageSize: 25,
        pageSizeOptions: ["25", "50", "100"],
        position: ["bottomLeft"],
        size: "default",
        itemRender: itemRender
    }} />

    const itemRender = (_: any, type: any, originalElement: any) => {
        console.log(type, "a");
        if (type === "prev") {
            return <a> <PaginationLeft /></a>;
        }
        if (type === "next") {
            return <a> <PaginationRight /></a>;
        }
        return originalElement;
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to custom like the one I made in the following link [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-table-custom-page-xxn0ck?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: thanks man I appreciate your effort, I thought there's an render element like next and prev button in pagination. So ended to custom the pagination on my own.

Comment: ah, sorry, I was wrong, I didn't know that the page was an error, I've revised it and I changed it with custom pagination, you can check the example above again. hope this help